# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error in jQuery. Table is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice regarding JQuery, so I need help regarding an issue with '$' not being defined. The main solution I saw when resolving the issue is to load JQuery first before the script which I tried

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="common.js"></script>
```

This are my functions, serverURL() is found in common.js:

```
<script>

 function displayleaderboard(){
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = serverURL() + "/leaderboard.php";

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  leaderboard(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
 };

 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

}

function leaderboard(response) {
var arr = 'response';
var i;

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

$("#standings").append("<tr><td><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/"+ arr[i].informant_pic + "' height='50'>" + "<b>" + arr[i].informant_name + arr[i].informant_score + "</b></td>");
}

}    

displayleaderboard();
leaderboard();

</script>
```

The error occurs on:

```
$("#standings").append("<tr><td><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/"+ arr[i].informant_pic + "' height='50'>"
    + "<b>" + arr[i].informant_name + arr[i].informant_score + "</b></td>");
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to use `jQuery("#standings")` in place of `$("#standings")` you are using 2 jquery frameworks and maby they are causing the issue

Comment: @Franco Where do you see two jquery frameworks? `jquery.mobile` is a jquery plugin that enhances it, it doesn't redefine it.

Comment: There seem to be two problems here. `undefined` in the table is because `arr[i].informant_name` and `arr[i].informant_score` are undefined. `$ is unedefined` is something else.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for pointing me on this. I never use this so, to be honest, I even didn't know it. When I see such kind of error the first think that I think is some collision will happen some where. You see this more often when people without also knowing will add several versions of `jquery`. I always learn something new from you all the time. :) :)

Comment: I am still wondering if you have tried what I propose in my first comment

Comment: @Franco, thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. Therefore it could be the other two at fault.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry I am very new to this so I do not know where the error lies. Is there a possibility that the php retrieval is at fault ?

Comment: I found my mistake. In function displayleaderboard, I have already let them know to run function leaderboard. However I made the Javascript run it again, therefore leaving me with unspecified variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get undefined since your array contain a string `'response'` then `arr[i].informant_name` and `arr[i].informant_score` will returns undefined.

Try to replace `'response'` by passed parameter `response` by removing the quotes and recheck :

```
var arr = response; //Removing quotes arround 'response'
```

**NOTE :** About `$ is not defined` i'm not sure but it may a conflit with another js library, try to use **[`jQuery.noConflict();`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)** and try also to replace dollar sign `$` by `jQuery` like **@Franco** mentioned in **[the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905741/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-error-in-jquery-table-is-showing-unde/39905789#comment-67097080)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would that cause it to complain that `$` is not defined?

Comment: Not sure but i could see in the picture that `arr[i]..` return undefined..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, thanks for suggestion. I tried your two methods but it did not work. Sorry.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  
I found my mistake. In function displayleaderboard, I have already let them know to run function leaderboard. However I made the Javascript run it again, therefore leaving me with unspecified variables